# mechanism by which open cv helps in converting the image to numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have started using OpenCV in Python recently. I understand that cv2.imread() helps in representing the image in terms of Numpy array but I wanted to understand how this is done. I know how they are stored in the computer in the form of an array but nowhere I have found how this pixel's info is converted to an integer in range 0-255 (for example grayscale). 'How' this conversion from pixel's viewable information to numerical information is happening under the hood and 'who' is doing it.

Can anyone please help me with their expertise? :)

Comment: The formats of JPEG/TIFF/PNG files are well documented - they have image width and height and colourspace near the start. `cv2.imread()` understands those file formats, allocates space to load the files and unpacks the pixels into the arrays for you. That's all.

Comment: “'How' this conversion from pixel's viewable information to numerical information is happening” I think you are asking how one goes from a color on the screen to a number—it’s actually the other way around, numbers are converted to a color by the display. The conversion from light of a given intensity and given combination of wavelengths is converted to numbers by the camera that takes the picture and stored as numbers in a file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell "The formats of JPEG/TIFF/PNG files are well documented" -- is this information specified in the image file signature?

Comment: @CrisLuengo so the conversion from pixels to array and array to the pixel is done by the camera and display respectively?

Comment: No, the specifications are in ISO standards, linked here... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics and here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG etc

Comment: OpenCV is an open-source software project. You could just look for the corresponding class and read into the code on [their github page](https://github.com/opencv/opencv).